# Custom View won't show with onDraw

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have built a custom view which extends `LinearLayout`. The view creates in its constructor several other views with a background of a shape I've created like this:

```
private void addBars()
{
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++)
    {
        if(bars[i] != null)
        {
            removeView(bars[i]);
        }
        View view = new View(getContext());
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_bars);
        if(i < onBarIndex)
        {
            setBarColor(view, offBarColorBelowIndex);
        }
        else if(i == onBarIndex)
        {
            setBarColor(view, onBarColor);
        }
        else
        {
            setBarColor(view, offBarAfterIndex);
        }
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int) barWidth, LOWEST_BAR_HEIGHT + BAR_HEIGHT_DIFFERENCE*i);
        params.setMargins(spaceBetweenBarsPixels, 0, spaceBetweenBarsPixels, 0);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;            
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        bars[i] = view;
        addView(view);
    }
}
```

The `onBarIndex` can be changed from the outside and inside like this:

```
public void setOnBarIndex(int index)
{
    onBarIndex = index;
    addBars();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is update the index continuously and thus let the view redraw itself after a certain amount of interval. I'm doing it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(recording && recorder != null)
    {
        int onIndex = (int)recorder.getOnIndex();
        setOnBarIndex(onIndex);
        postInvalidateDelayed(ANIMATION_INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the `onDraw` method is present, the view is simply not drawing itself and the place in the layout where the view is supposed to be, seems blank. The `onDraw` method itself IS being called continuously and the recorder object can yield different results every time. If I comment the `onDraw` method then the view is showing like its supposed to, but then it won't redraw itself every interval.

Why is that?

Comment: Are you using <my.package.name.MyDrawView /> as the reference to your custom view ?

Comment: It's a bad habit to invalidate from onDraw. It's just like a recursive call.

Comment: Yes on the first question. For the second, its not like a recursive call but more like reinvoking it many times